# access to dynamic query params in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, query-string

i have a project with nextjs and i have a route like this => /categories/224?brand[0]=6.
i want when ever this query changed forExample /categories/224?brand[0]=8 my useEffect run again
this is my useEffect

```js
    const router = useRouter();

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('hey there');
},[])
```

i don't want my useEffect run when ever whole router.query change i just it runs when ever router.query.brand[0] changed.

Comment: Have you tried adding `router.query.brand` to the `useEffect`'s dependencies array?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer first would be to put the variable you want to control the useEffect in its dependency array

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello')
}, [router.query.brand])
```

as juiliomalves pointed out.

Now every change in `router.query.brand` will trigger this useEffect code.
However, other router changes could effect the page in general regardless of your useEffect.

Answer (score -3):

```js
    const router = useRouter();

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('hey there');
},[])
```

Comment: This is a copy of OP's code snippet - how does this address OP's question?